# Is the relation $R$ on $\Bbb N$ given by $(a,b)\in R\iff a\mid b$ an equivalence relation?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

$R \subset \Bbb N \times \Bbb N$

Is this an equivalence relation?

$$R=\{(a,b)\in \Bbb N\times \Bbb N\,:\,a\mid b\}$$

I would argue that it is reflexive because $a\mid a$, but it is not symmetric because $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$ are different.

I am not sure why it was claimed to be an equivalence relation in a previous math exam.

Comment: Give a counterexample to show that the relation is not symmetric and hence not an equivalence relation. For example $2\mid6$ but $6\nmid2$.

Comment: not an equivalence

Comment: @BillDubuque That was a question from a previous math exam and the answer to it was "true". In other word it is supposed to be an equivalence relation. It seems that my prof made a typo.

Comment: @MaikKlein Thanks, I added that to your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an equivalence relation because it isn't symmetric (despite the symmetric nature of the divisibility notation). This can be seen through a variety of counterexample, such as: $$2 \mid 4 \quad \text{but} \quad 4 \not\mid 2.$$

In fact, it is never symmetric (apart from when $a=b$) because $a \mid b$ requires $a \leq b$ whilst $b \mid a$ requires $b \leq a$.

Comment: ["Never use a symmetric symbol for an asymmetric relation!"](http://mathoverflow.net/a/18619/32499)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [Zain Patel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/161779), divisibility is not an equivalence relation because it is not symmetric.

However, since divisibility is reflexive, [antisymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation), and transitive, then it is a [*partial order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).